# How do I write a PowerShell alias that changes directory and lists all files and folders?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a command like `cs *directory*` that will change directories and list all items immediately. How would I do this with PowerShell?

Comment: `cs` would be an alias, not a function.

Comment: You combine `cd` with an `ls` or `gci`!  ;-)  Why would you like to re-invent the wheel for something that trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function. Example:

```
function cs {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [String] $path
  )
  Set-Location -LiteralPath $path -ErrorAction Stop
  Get-ChildItem
}
```